# How to display json string in the form of a table in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I want to display a json string returned in the result of an ajax call in the from of a table. My ajax code is :

```
var table = $('#PartnersTable');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("Get","Home")',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            // Code here
        });
```

I have tried many solution , that are on stackoverflow but they didn't work. Thanks in advance

This is my action code :

```
public ActionResult Get()
        {
            Home h = new Home();
            return Json(h.get(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: You to iterate through each record in data and create required TR TD for it... or else you can use jqGrid plugin as well

Comment: How do I access the record ? data.ID , data.Name ?

Comment: please post the object which you are sending from the Home/Get Action...
Or else please post the Action method code itself... if you are sending a single object then it will have data.PROPERTYNAME (data.ID) BUT if you are sending array of object then it will be data[0].ID and so on....

Comment: I used alert(data[0].ID) , but it is not displaying anything

Comment: What this h.get() method returns ??/

Comment: It returns "undefined" , I have placed my action code above , you can see it

Comment: I suggest you use `Fiddler`, or the dev tools in your browser, to capture what is being returned from the action method. That way you know precisely what data is coming back.

Comment: It returns this string {"Homes":[{"ID":2,"Name":"Hammad"},{"ID":3,"Name":"dsda"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering that your h.get() method will returns object which has following properties...

```
{"Homes"
      :[
         {"ID":2,"Name":"Hammad"},
         {"ID":3,"Name":"dsda"} 
        ]
}
```

These values will get accessed in following manner

```
data.Homes[0].ID
data.Homes[0].Name
```

Comment: I have placed data.ID in a alert() , but it is saying "undefined"

Comment: It returns this string {"Homes":[{"ID":2,"Name":"Hammad"},{"ID":3,"Name":"dsda"}

Comment: Cheers !!!
Please mark this as correct answer if you got the expected solution..
Thanks